# Which dim to use on tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-algebra

I'm confused about which `dim` refers to which actual dimension in Tensorflow in general, but concretely, when using [tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_cosine_distance)

Given

```
x = [
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
]
```

I'd like to calculate the distance column-wise. In other words, which dimension resolves to (pseudo code):

```
mean([
    cosine_distance(x[0][0], x[1][0]),
    cosine_distance(x[0][1], x[1][1]),
    cosine_distance(x[0][2], x[1][2]),
    cosine_distance(x[0][3], x[1][3]),
    cosine_distance(x[0][4], x[1][4]),
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is along `dim 0` for your input `x`. It's intuitive to see this once you construct your input `x` as a numpy array.

```
In [49]: x_arr = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)

In [50]: x_arr
Out[50]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]], dtype=float32)


# compute (mean) cosine distance between `x[0]` & `x[1]`
# where `x[0]` can be considered as `labels`
# while `x[1]` can be considered as `predictions`
In [51]: cosine_dist_axis0 = tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance(x_arr[0], x_arr[1], 0)
```

---

This `dim` corresponds to the name `axis` in NumPy terminology. For example, a simple `sum` operation can be done along `axis 0` like:

```
In [52]: x_arr
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]], dtype=float32)

In [53]: np.sum(x_arr, axis=0)
Out[53]: array([  1.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.], dtype=float32)
```

---

When you compute the [**`tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_cosine_distance), you're essentially computing the *cosine* distance between the vectors `labels` and `predictions` along `dim 0` (and then taking mean) if your inputs are of shape `(n, )` where `n` is the length of each vector (i.e. number of entries in labels/prediction)

But, if you're passing the `labels` and `predictions` as a ***column vector***, then the [**`tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_cosine_distance)  has to be calculated along `dim 1`

**Example**:

If your input `label` and `prediction` are column vectors,

```
# if your `label` is a column vector
In [66]: (x_arr[0])[:, None]
Out[66]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]], dtype=float32)

# if your `prediction` is a column vector
In [67]: (x_arr[1])[:, None]
Out[67]: 
array([[ 0.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]], dtype=float32)
```

Then, [**`tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_cosine_distance) has to computed along `dim 1`

```
# inputs
In [68]: labels = (x_arr[0])[:, None]
In [69]: predictions = (x_arr[1])[:, None]

# compute mean cosine distance between them
In [70]: cosine_dist_dim1 = tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance(labels, predictions, 1)
```

---

This [**`tf.metrics.mean_cosine_distance`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_cosine_distance) is more or less doing the same thing as [**`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) but it also takes `mean`.

For your example case:

```
In [77]: x
Out[77]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

In [78]: import scipy

In [79]: scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(x[0], x[1])
Out[79]: 0.009132
```

---